# Get Object insinde JSON Object

Tags: python, json

I am pretty new to JSON and need to get an Object inside a list of JSON Objects.
This is my data structure and code so far:

```
{
  "nhits": 15,
  "parameters": {
    "dataset": "100073",
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "q": "timestamp:[2021-02-21T23:00:00Z TO 2021-03-08T22:59:59Z]",
    "rows": 10,
    "start": 0,
    "sort": [
      "timestamp"
    ],
    "format": "json",
    "facet": [
      "timestamp"
    ]
  },
  "records": [
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "a1252522b7820edd98eb464811953d0f6ba56458",
      "fields": {
        "week": 10,
        "ncumul_conf": 9971,
        "current_quarantined": 506,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-08T09:30:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9627,
        "ndiff_conf": 4,
        "current_quarantined_total": 623,
        "current_hosp_resident": 13,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 152,
        "current_hosp": 19,
        "ndiff_released": 10,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 6,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 117,
        "time": "10:30",
        "date": "2021-03-08",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 5,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "c1a9f3fd45008ef3c140e446303ab3c2906166e0",
      "fields": {
        "week": 9,
        "ncumul_conf": 9967,
        "current_quarantined": 468,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-07T11:40:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9617,
        "ndiff_conf": 13,
        "current_quarantined_total": 646,
        "current_hosp_resident": 14,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 158,
        "current_hosp": 20,
        "ndiff_released": 16,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 6,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 178,
        "time": "12:40",
        "date": "2021-03-07",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 5,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "3668aa9ae4f9cf73890ad8c7f13efef7246cc461",
      "fields": {
        "week": 9,
        "ncumul_conf": 9954,
        "current_quarantined": 417,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-06T11:20:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9601,
        "ndiff_conf": 22,
        "current_quarantined_total": 602,
        "current_hosp_resident": 13,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 161,
        "current_hosp": 19,
        "ndiff_released": 23,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 6,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 185,
        "time": "12:20",
        "date": "2021-03-06",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 5,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "96a2bfde464cb4664ae8b16723960a7141800e56",
      "fields": {
        "week": 9,
        "ncumul_conf": 9932,
        "current_quarantined": 345,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-05T09:50:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9578,
        "ndiff_conf": 25,
        "current_quarantined_total": 550,
        "current_hosp_resident": 12,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 162,
        "current_hosp": 20,
        "ndiff_released": 14,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 8,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 205,
        "time": "10:50",
        "date": "2021-03-05",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 6,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "37a9b2c6a896a7dff362b27b671c71b83f467ccd",
      "fields": {
        "week": 9,
        "ncumul_conf": 9907,
        "current_quarantined": 253,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-04T09:40:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9564,
        "ndiff_conf": 27,
        "current_quarantined_total": 481,
        "current_hosp_resident": 13,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 151,
        "current_hosp": 21,
        "ndiff_released": 23,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 8,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 228,
        "time": "10:40",
        "date": "2021-03-04",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 6,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "c7933687391ff92436f1a75503648ce9430e0baa",
      "fields": {
        "week": 9,
        "ncumul_conf": 9880,
        "current_quarantined": 241,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-03T10:50:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9541,
        "ndiff_conf": 13,
        "current_quarantined_total": 467,
        "current_hosp_resident": 15,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 147,
        "current_hosp": 23,
        "ndiff_released": 15,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 8,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 226,
        "time": "11:50",
        "date": "2021-03-03",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 7,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "dd830a16c7f18e6cc2d5f8b03f5a75437d1331d3",
      "fields": {
        "week": 9,
        "ncumul_conf": 9867,
        "current_quarantined": 197,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-02T09:40:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9526,
        "ndiff_conf": 28,
        "current_quarantined_total": 419,
        "current_hosp_resident": 15,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 149,
        "current_hosp": 22,
        "ndiff_released": 27,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 7,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 222,
        "time": "10:40",
        "date": "2021-03-02",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 7,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "4de6410562c2e0329a9395f8e7687ed098f788b6",
      "fields": {
        "week": 9,
        "ncumul_conf": 9839,
        "current_quarantined": 159,
        "timestamp": "2021-03-01T09:40:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9499,
        "ndiff_conf": -14,
        "current_quarantined_total": 365,
        "current_hosp_resident": 15,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 148,
        "current_hosp": 21,
        "ndiff_released": -4,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 6,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 206,
        "time": "10:40",
        "date": "2021-03-01",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 7,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "90006046ef1f6627c4c742520e37c99c04eb2db3",
      "fields": {
        "week": 8,
        "ncumul_conf": 9853,
        "current_quarantined": 167,
        "timestamp": "2021-02-28T08:00:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9503,
        "ndiff_conf": 13,
        "current_quarantined_total": 358,
        "current_hosp_resident": 10,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 158,
        "current_hosp": 16,
        "ndiff_released": 14,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 6,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 191,
        "time": "09:00",
        "date": "2021-02-28",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 7,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    },
    {
      "datasetid": "100073",
      "recordid": "41c0f47f811b68f3ca393546e202b1b698e741c1",
      "fields": {
        "week": 8,
        "ncumul_conf": 9840,
        "current_quarantined": 177,
        "timestamp": "2021-02-27T09:30:00+00:00",
        "source": "https://www.gesundheit.bs.ch",
        "ncumul_released": 9489,
        "ndiff_conf": 21,
        "current_quarantined_total": 359,
        "current_hosp_resident": 10,
        "ncumul_deceased": 192,
        "current_isolated": 159,
        "current_hosp": 16,
        "ndiff_released": 14,
        "current_hosp_non_resident": 6,
        "current_quarantined_riskareatravel": 182,
        "time": "10:30",
        "date": "2021-02-27",
        "ndiff_deceased": 0,
        "current_icu": 7,
        "abbreviation_canton_and_fl": "BS"
      },
      "record_timestamp": "2021-03-08T21:01:15.004000+00:00"
    }
  ],
  "facet_groups": [
    {
      "facets": [
        {
          "count": 15,
          "path": "2021",
          "state": "displayed",
          "name": "2021"
        }
      ],
      "name": "timestamp"
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the data in the "records" list i use:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url = 'https://data.bs.ch/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=100073&q=timestamp%3A%5B2021-02-21T23%3A00%3A00Z+TO+2021-03-08T22%3A59%3A59Z%5D&sort=timestamp&facet=timestamp'
ddict = {}
def getDataFromBS():
    json_url = urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(json_url.read())
    records = data['records']
    
getDataFromBS()
```

My problem now is, that i need to get the data inside the "fields" object. But i don't know how to extract it. Can anyone help me? Even if it is just a hint.

Every help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `data` is a python dictionary. You can use it like any other dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return something from your function.  The `records` field is a list of dictionaries.  You can iterate over them and pull out the `fields` object

```
def getDataFromBS():
    json_url = urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(json_url.read())
    records = data['records']
    fields = [r.get('fields') for r in records]
    return fields
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've made my live so much easier!

Answer (score 1):

You could directly do `data['records'][0]['fields']` after `data = getDataFromBS()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Use @James answer as it doesn't throw an error if "fields" doesn't exist.

Comment: Definitely! I only proposed a direct answer since the function is not generic.

Comment: Actually, just for information, my answer would return a 'KeyError: 'field'' while @James answer would return '[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]' with no error message.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the answer already, but here is another alternative if you jsut want to return 1 field.  You could add a loop and iterate over the others

```
import json

with open('test.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print(data['records'][1]['fields'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)